# Magento 2 cache issue

Tags: magento2, cache, full-page-cache, php-7

I have been struggling with a problem for few days now and am not bale to solve it.

I run Magento 2.2.2 on a Linux VPS with PHP7.1

First I developed site on a development domain dev.mydomain.com everything worked great cache was creaeted and served. When site was ready I cahnged domein name from dev. to www.mydomain.com this was an existing domain point to other directory first.

I changed domains in index.php (it is multistore) and changed in DB this is normal procedure I always do and it always works.

Now live site works and cache is created but pages do not load the cache. I really am puzzled what is causing this. I did all standard things flush cache, compile etc. Struggling if it is sever relate or Magento.

Anybody a clue on where to look?

Thanks,
Maco

Comment: Have you check where all cache enable or nor?

Comment: Like I said, it is just a domain change nothing else was changed. Before domain name change it worked and after it stopped.

Comment: Try running these commands

if production mode is enabled skip this

`php bin/magento deploy:mode:set production`

`php bin/magento setup:upgrade`

`php bin/magento setup:di:compile `

`php bin/magento cache:enable`

Comment: Did all that no luck, still same issue.